# 'setProgress not a function' error while setting progress value of a progress bar

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I want to set value of a progress bar in an accordian but I am encountering 'setProgress is not a function' error. Any idea what's wrong with following code.

Observation:
If I move the progress bar out of the Accordian then the error goes away and the progress bar appears fine.

I want to set the progress bar eventually to {repMonitor.currentItem.threatLevel} but for now I am just testing with hypothetical threat value i.e 60

```
<mx:Accordion id="monAccordian" includeIn="Monitoring" x="10" y="10" width="554" height="242" change="monAccordianChange()" >       
   <mx:Repeater id="repMonitor" dataProvider="{monitoringArray}">
      <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="{repMonitor.currentItem.firstName+' '+ repMonitor.currentItem.lastName}" >
        <mx:Image x="10" y="10" source="{repMonitor.currentItem.imageName}" width="175" height="118"/>
        <s:Label x="200" y="14" text="Threat Level:"/>
          <mx:ProgressBar x="200" y="30" mode="manual" label="" id="bar" width="200" creationComplete="bar.setProgress(60,100);" />
      </mx:Canvas>
   </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stems from the fact that your ProgressBar is in a repeater. You cannot reference the repeated items by id because you would have a variable number of ProgressBars with id "bar".

There are also special considerations when using event listeners inside of Repeater objects:

> **Event handlers in Repeater components**
>
> When a Repeater component is busy
>   repeating, each repeated object that
>   it creates can bind at that moment to
>   the Repeater component's currentItem
>   property, which is changing as the
>   Repeater component repeats. You cannot
>   give each instance its own event
>   handler by writing something like
>   click="doSomething({r.currentItem})"
>   because binding expressions are not
>   allowed in event handlers, and all
>   instances of the repeated component
>   must share the same event handler.
>
> Repeated components and repeated
>   Repeater components have a
>   getRepeaterItem() method that returns
>   the item in the dataProvider property
>   that was used to produce the object.
>   When the Repeater component finishes
>   repeating, you can use the
>   getRepeaterItem() method to determine
>   what the event handler should do based
>   on the currentItem property. To do so,
>   you pass the
>   event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem()
>   method to the event handler. The
>   getRepeaterItem() method takes an
>   optional index that specifies which
>   Repeater components you want when
>   nested Repeater components are
>   present; the 0 index is the outermost
>   Repeater component. If you do not
>   specify the index argument, the
>   innermost Repeater component is
>   implied.

You can read more about this [in the Repeater docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=repeater_3.html).

Comment: Thanks Sean for replying. Can I use this getRepeaterItem to set my progressBar to repMonitor.currentItem.threatlevel?