# How can I user getRepeaterItem to set the progress of a progress bar?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a progress bar inside a repeater and therefore I will need to use getRepeaterItem to set it's progress as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160887/setprogress-not-a-function-error-while-setting-progress-value-of-a-progress-bar) question.

How can I do that such that the value of progress may be taken from repMonitor.currentItem.threatLevel?

```
<mx:Accordion id="monAccordian" includeIn="Monitoring" x="10" y="10" width="554" height="242" change="monAccordianChange()" >       
   <mx:Repeater id="repMonitor" dataProvider="{monitoringArray}">
      <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="{repMonitor.currentItem.firstName+' '+ repMonitor.currentItem.lastName}" >
        <mx:Image x="10" y="10" source="{repMonitor.currentItem.imageName}" width="175" height="118"/>
        <s:Label x="200" y="14" text="Threat Level:"/>
          <mx:ProgressBar x="200" y="30" mode="manual" label="" id="bar" width="200" />
      </mx:Canvas>
   </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function needs to be called every time threatLevel changes in order to update Repeater items:

```
        private function updateProgresses() : void
        {
            if (!bar) return;
            for (var i : int = 0; i < bar.length; i++)
            {
                var p : ProgressBar = bar[i] as ProgressBar;
                if (p)
                {
                    p.setProgress(monitoringArray[i].threatLevel, 100);
                }
            }
        }
```